# UIWindow shows the status bar - can't make it go away

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, statusbar, uiwindow

I have an iOS 7 only app.
It uses the key `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to YES so that each view controller controls the appearance of the status bar.
Of course, in this case iOS ignores calls to `UIApplication`'s `setStatusBarHidden:` and it's variants.
The problems starts when I show a `UIWindow` over a `UIViewController` that sets the status bar to hidden.
As soon as the `UIWindow` becomes visible, the status bar appears, and I can't hide it.

Assuming the status bar is currently hidden using `-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` , as soon as I run the following piece of code, the status bar re-appears, and I can't turn it off.
Suggestions, anyone?

```
    static UIWindow* w = nil; // testing code, makes sure w does not autodestruct...
    if (!w){
        CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        w = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:r];
        w.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    [w makeKeyAndVisible]; // colors the screen green, but shows the status bar
```